# Bootstrap table two horizontal columns of varied lengths in each row

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table I decorated with bootstrap.
 Here is the simple table view (collapsed).

[image: Image Hosted by ImageShack.us]

Each table row has two horizontal sets of data. So the expanded view for each row shows up when the "Details" button is clicked. Here's the expanded view.

[image: Image Hosted by ImageShack.us]

The first set of data of each row has 4 columns. While I'd like the second set of data of the same row to fully occupy the whole table width.

The problem is that the way I did it doesn't feel the best way to do it. 
I pretty much used Angular loop construct to repeat the `<tr>`. I then embedded two tables per `<tr>` so that I can display the first data set in the first table and the expanded view in the second table.  Clicking on the "Details" button shows the second set (table) of data of row.

```
<table class="table-hover table-condensed">
    <!--<table class="table">-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" class="span2">Date</th>
            <th align="left" class="span2">Title</th>
            <th align="left" class="span2">Bill Total</th>
            <th align="left" class="span4">Options</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="ibill in user.groups[0].bills | filter:query | orderBy:'date'">
            <td colspan="4">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="span2">{{ ibill.billDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                        <td class="span2">{{ ibill.title }}</td>
                        <td class="span2">${{ ibill.billTotal }}</td>
                        <td class="span4">
                            <!-- <a ng-click='deleteBill(ibill.id)'><i class="icon-trash "></i></a>
                                <a  href="#/bills/edit/0/{{$index}}"><i class="icon-pencil "></i></a>--> <a ng-click='deleteBill(ibill.id)' class="btn btn-mini" ng-init="ibill.isCollapsed = 'true'" ng-click="ibill.isCollapsed = !ibill.isCollapsed"><i class=" icon-trash"></i></a>
 <a href="#/bills/edit/0/{{$index}}" class="btn btn-mini" ng-init="ibill.isCollapsed = 'true'" ng-click="ibill.isCollapsed = !ibill.isCollapsed"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
 <a class="btn btn-mini" ng-init="ibill.isCollapsed = 'true'" ng-click="ibill.isCollapsed = !ibill.isCollapsed"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i>&nbsp;details</a>

                            <!--<a class="btn" ng-init="ibill.isCollapsed=' true'" ng-click="ibill.isCollapsed=! ibill.isCollapsed"><i class="icon-folder-open "></i> Details</a>-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            <div collapse="ibill.isCollapsed">
                                <div>
                                    <p ng-repeat="simplecost in ibill.billSimpleEntry.simpleUserIdAndLiableCost">{{simplecost.user.fName}} owes ${{simplecost.liableCost}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <!--<td>{{ibill}}</td>-->
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr>
                          <td><div collapse="ibill.isCollapsed">
                            <div class="well well-large">Some content</div> 
                    </div></td>
                      </tr>-->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm pretty much e

```
<table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to do the same with a table-less design (eliminating two tables per row)

Comment: `<div class="span8 ">   <p ng-r` why is `"span8"` there?

Comment: @Fresheyeball I removed it. Realized that it's not needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the colspan attribute on a td to achieve the same effect without the tables. Ex:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr> <!--normal row stuff-->
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='4'><!--details stuff here--></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, the td with colspan='4' will be a single cell that is the same width as the 4 cells in the previous row.

Comment: I did think of this approach. The only issue I had with this is that the AngularJS construct 'ng-repeat' cannot be split across two <tr> tags. So either I can put it in the first <tr> or the second <tr> which will only loop one of <tr> tags. But this is the cleanest approach and I'm trying to see if I can solve the loop problem. Thanks.